# Improve performance of accessing elements in a map and writing to a file

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, data-structures

I have a map structure in C++ which holds about 60 million  pairs. After I populate the map, I would like to write it to a plain file.

At the moment this code is quite slow and I'm wondering if you have any suggestions on how I can speed up the writing?

Can I 1) Improve the way in which elements are accessed in the map? OR 2) by speeding up file writing itself?

```
map<int,std::pair<int, int>> myMap;
//populate map
typedef map<int,std::pair<int, int>>::const_iterator MapIterator;
int cnt=0;

for (MapIterator iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); ++iter)
{     
    ofile<<iter->second.first<<","<<iter->second.second<<"\n";
    //just printing every 1 million edges written.
    cnt++;
    if(cnt%1000000==0)
        cout<<cnt<<endl;
}
```

Note that I have to use a data structure that preserves order of the keys (i.e. a map)

Comment: What is "quite slow"? Writing 60 million lines to a file might take "a while".

Comment: You might be able to speed up the writing by first writing to a `std::ostringstream` and writing the result to disk in one big chunk afterwards.

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: How much CPU time is used to write the file?  It should be close to zero CPU time as you should be blocking on IO waits.  If CPU utilization isn't almost zero, you need to use a less CPU-intensive method to write your data - C++ streams are usually pretty CPU-intensive.  And finally, profile your application to make sure you're working on the actual performance bottlenecks.

Comment: If, for instance, you ran your test under VS' debug configuration, then it should be slow. And what means "slow"? Seconds, minutes?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by CPU time? and what is a less CPU-intensive method?

Comment: To determine a maximum bound for your "room for improvement", you can write *one* pair 60 million times and measure that. Your code is always going to be slower.

Comment: @ZDF I'm using Xcode on OSX. It takes about 6-7 minutes to write the file.

Comment: And if you want something that's fast, store binary, not text. There's a fair chance that most of your processing time goes towards making strings out of ints.

Comment: @kami 6-7 minutes doesn't sound unreasonable when you involve conversion to strings; it's around 60-70 microseconds per pair.

Comment: Storing in memory and writing to a file at once in the end might be faster, I think. I/O usually takes a while and is a heavy operation and should be done less frequently. I had read this on other SO answers. Do try this out and let me know how it goes. :)

Answer (score 4):

On my machine (i7/16gb/win7/vs2013), the example below runs in about:

- 6s (c stream/binary);
- 22s (c stream/text);
- 9s (c++ stream/binary) and
- 56s (c++ stream/text).

On a different machine (PentiumD/4gb/win10/vs2015), the longest time was about 4 minutes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  typedef std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t> C_Value;
  typedef std::map< uint32_t, C_Value > C_Map;

  //
  C_Map m;
  const uint32_t maxsize = 50000000;
  try
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxsize; ++i )
      m[i] = C_Value( i, i );
  }
  catch ( ... )
  {
    std::cout << "too many elements\n";
    return -1;
  }

  //
  std::cout << "writing " << m.size() << " elements... ";
  auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

#if 1
  //
  FILE* f = fopen( "test.bin", "wb" );
  if ( ! f )
  {
    std::cout << "could not open file\n";
    return -2;
  }

  //
  for ( auto e : m )
  {
    fwrite( &e.second.first, sizeof e.second.first, 1, f );
    fwrite( &e.second.second, sizeof e.second.second, 1, f );
  }

  //
  fclose( f );
#endif
#if 0
  //
  FILE* f = fopen( "test.bin", "w" );
  if ( ! f )
  {
    std::cout << "could not open file\n";
    return -2;
  }

  //
  for ( auto e : m )
  {
    fprintf( f, "%d, %d\n", e.second.first, e.second.second );
  }

  //
  fclose( f );
#endif
#if 0
  std::ofstream os( "test.bin", std::ios::binary );
  if ( ! os )
  {
    std::cout << "could not open file\n";
    return -2;
  }

  //
  for ( auto e : m )
  {
    os.write( (const char*)&e.second.first, sizeof e.second.first );
    os.write( (const char*)&e.second.second, sizeof e.second.second );
  }

  //
  os.close();
#endif
#if 0
  std::ofstream os( "test.bin" );
  if ( ! os )
  {
    std::cout << "could not open file\n";
    return -2;
  }

  //
  for ( auto e : m )
  {
    os << e.second.first << ',' << e.second.second << '\n';
  }

  //
  os.close();
#endif

  //
  auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "done in [ms]: " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>( t_end-t_start ).count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Interesting that C++ streams are about an order of magnitude slower than binary IO and about three times slower than C-style `fprintf()`.  I do wonder what unbuffered simple `open()`/`write()`/`close()` does in comparison to the tests you've already run.

Comment: @Andrew Henle _"...an order of magnitude slower..."_. Not really. I have updated the answer to make it clear. _"I do wonder what unbuffered..."_ It is extremely slow. I did try it once (I have used Windows' API).

Comment: @Snps _"...using os.sync_with_stdio(false)..."_ This would make sense for a standard stream (like `stdin/cin`), not for an arbitrary file stream.

Comment: thanks. this is very useful. however I cannot write the file in binary as the next step needs the file in text format. But it's useful to know c stream/text is faster.

Comment: @kami Unless you have a slow machine, your time is dubious. You should try my example on your machine, for comparison.

Comment: BTW, there's a big difference between an i7 Nehalem (first gen i7) vs. an i7 Skylake.  For single-threaded performance, potentially more difference than between an i3 and and i7 of the same generation.  Not really relevant here, but if I was giving specs for my machine in a super-short format, I'd say 3.7GHz SnB / Linux / gcc 5.3 -O3 or something.  I haven't tried this myself, so IDK how much it's CPU limited vs. disk I/O (and how much difference more RAM might make).  The effects of more RAM are going to depend heavily on the OS's buffering (dirty page writeback policy / tuning).