# Parse raw data fast with specific format

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, unordered-map

I am searching ways to read a text file fast, really fast. I have thought of many solution but could not reach to an optimal one. Let me describe my problem and then I shall write the things I already tried.

Problem statement:

Say I have an 10G text file and the format of that file is:

```
___PART_1___
*1 abc
*2 def
...
<5 million lines of this format>
*5000001 blah

___PART_2___
1 *1:1 *2:2 <value1>
2 *3:1 *4:3 <value2>
3 *4:2 *4:4 <value3>
<another 10 million lines of this format>
```

In **_PART_1_**, There are two columns, ID and NAME.
In **_PART_2_**, There are 4 columns, Serial number, data1, data2, some_value

What we want from this huge file is to get the data before colons from data1 and data2 column. In this case, we would want

from 1st row of **_PART_2_**, extract *1 and *2, get the corresponding name from **_PART_1_** which is abc & def in this case.
from 2nd row of **_PART_2_**, extract *3 and *4, get the corresponding name from **_PART_1_** whatever they are.

That is all information we want.

Things to keep in consideration before we jump to conclusion:

In **_PART_1_**, ID's might not be unique or consecutive and there could be any number of lines, 5 million is just an number.

In **_PART_2_**, It is certain that there would be an entry in **_PART_1_** for the data before colons from data1 and data2 column of **PART_2_**.

Tried so far:
Number 1 : I have tried keeping the **_PART_1_** into map but since the number of entries are quite big, balancing would itself take much time. So, I confirmed myself on unordered_map. Will write a good hashing function as well for it. And then whenever I reaches **_PART_2_**, tokenize that line, get second/third token, tokenize them again and get the data. Finally, look for them into the unordered_map. Used boost::tokenizer to tokenizer.

Number 2 : Instead of boost::tokenizer, worked with regex_searches as well but they also seem to be slow.

Number 2 : Mapped files to memory using mmap but since the file is huge, my program ran out of memory sometimes.

Code snapshot, not full code:

```
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m_unordered;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator m_unordered_itr;

int main() {
  m_unordered un_name_map;
  m_unordered_itr un_name_map_itr;
  boost::char_separator<char> space_sep{" "};
  std::ifstream myfile("file.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    bool part1_starts = 0;
    bool part2_starts = 0;
    while ( std::getline (myfile,line) ) {
      if (line.find("___PART_1___") != std::string::npos) {
        part1_starts = 1;
        continue;
      }
      if (mapping_starts) {
        tokenizer tok{line, space_sep};
        tokenizer::iterator it = tok.begin();
        std::string index = *it++;
        std::string value = *it;
        un_name_map.insert(un_name_map.end(), {index, value});
      }
      if (line.find("___PART_2___") != std::string::npos) {
        part2_starts = 1;
        part1_starts = 0;
        continue;
      }
      if (part2_starts) {
        tokenizer tok{line, space_sep};
        tokenizer::iterator it_start = tok.begin();
        // Ignore first token and advance
        std::advance(it_start, 1);

        // Split the second token which is my second column of ___PART_2___             vector<std::string> strs;
        strs.reserve(2);
        boost::split(strs, *it_start, boost::is_any_of(":"));
        un_name_map_itr = un_name_map.find(strs[0]);
        if (un_name_map_itr != un_name_map.end()) {
         std::cout << "1. Name from the map is " << un_name_map_itr->second << std::endl;
        }

        // Split the third token which is my third column of ___PART_2___
        // Similar code as above.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am sure that there are better ways to reach to the mentioned solution. I look forward to all of them.
Only and only thing I care about is 'SPEED'. I will be happy to write more details about it, if needed.

Comment: First of all, you are asking a general community for a solution to a very specific problem. Not many people have the time or desire to dig into something this detailed, especially considering that it won't be useful to many other people. As an answer to your question, you seem to be doing the right thing with unordered_map. I guess you could get a higher speed if you read the whole file into memory (as a char array) and then manipulated it there. You could also try to avoid the boost tokenizer and do tokenizing yourself - but there is no telling how much faster it will be before you try it.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745078/improve-performance-of-accessing-elements-in-a-map-and-writing-to-a-file/34748845#34748845

Comment: @PlinyTheElder, I see. What would you suggest for tokenizing then?

Comment: You could perform tokenizing with "manual" string handling - that is, cycling though characters and looking for separators. In your case, the separators are '\n', space, and ':'. It's not as convenient, but could be faster.